# Angular firebase subscribe function called twice

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, mapbox

I'm trying to make button on popup on marker in a map with mapbox-gl. These buttons allows to subscribe/unsubscribe to a place.
But when I click on them, I saw that the subscribe function is called twice and make the result bug.

This is on the third function below.

```
loadPlaces() {
this.placeService.getAll().subscribe(
    (places: Place[]) => {
      this.places = places;
      this.places.forEach((place: Place) => {

        const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 })
            .setDOMContent(this.setPopUpContent(place));

        new mapboxgl.Marker({color: 'red'})
            .setLngLat(place.coordinates)
            .setPopup(popup)
            .addTo(this.map);
      });
    }
);
```

}

```
setPopUpContent(place: Place) {
const popupContent = document.createElement('div');

const title = document.createElement('p');
title.innerText = place.name;

const button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerText = 'Subscribe';
this.setSubscribeButton(place, button);

popupContent.append(title, button);
return popupContent;
```

}

```
setSubscribeButton(place: Place, button: any) {
  this.placeSubscriptionService.isSubscribed(this.authService.getCurrentUser().uid, place.id).subscribe(subscribed => {
      console.log(subscribed);
      if (!subscribed) {
          button.innerHTML = 'Subscribe';
          button.onclick = () => {
              this.subscribe(place);
          };
      } else {
          button.innerHTML = 'Unsubscribe';
          button.onclick = () => {
              this.unsubscribe(place);
          };
      }
  });
```

}

```
subscribe(place: Place) {
const placeSubscription: any = {
  userId: this.authService.getCurrentUser().uid,
  placeId: place.id
};
this.placeSubscriptionService.create(placeSubscription);
```

}

```
unsubscribe(place) {
  this.placeSubscriptionService.getSubscriptionId(this.authService.getCurrentUser().uid, place.id).subscribe(subscriptionId => {
      this.placeSubscriptionService.delete(subscriptionId);
  });
```

}

And here the code in the service to ckeck if the user is subscribed to the place on firestore :

```
isSubscribed(userId: string, placeId: string): Observable<boolean> {
return this.firestore.collection<PlaceSubscription>(this.collectionName, ref => ref
    .where('userId', '==', userId)
    .where('placeId', '==', placeId))
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(map(placeSubscriptions => {
      const placeSubscription = placeSubscriptions[0];
      if (placeSubscription) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }));
```

}

When I display the result of the function isSubscribed when I click on the button for subscribing to the place, it returns twice 'true'. And after cliking on the button to unsubscribe once to the place, when I re subscribe, it returns me twice true and finally false. So I can't subscribe to the place anymore because it goes to true and false directly.

Is there a thing that I do wrong ?

Thank you very much for your time.

Edit :

```
let subscription: Subscription;

        const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 })
            .on('open', () => {
                console.log('open');
                subscription = this.placeSubscriptionService.isSubscribed(this.authService.getCurrentUser().uid, place.id)
                    .pipe(first()).subscribe(
                    subscribed => {
                        console.log(subscribed);
                        popup.setDOMContent(this.setPopUpContent(place, subscribed));
                    });
            })
            .on('close', () => {
                if (subscription) {
                    subscription.unsubscribe();
                }
            });




setPopUpContent(place: Place, subscribed: boolean) {
const popupContent = document.createElement('div');
const title = document.createElement('p');
title.innerText = place.name;

const button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerText = 'Subscribe';
if (subscribed) {
    button.innerText = 'Unsubscribe';
    button.onclick = () => {
        this.unsubscribe(place);
    };
} else {
    button.innerText = 'Subscribe';
    button.onclick = () => {
        this.subscribe(place);
    };
}
popupContent.append(title, button);
return popupContent;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of code involved in here, (if you can provide minimal reproducible code people can help you better)

Any way what I see as problem, is you never unsubscribe from the observable and as many as you call `loadPlaces` it will call more and more

One way to fix is below code, as `first()` cause your subscription be ended

```
this.placeService.getAll()
.pipe(
  first()
)
.subscribe(
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I update my code, which I add on my post, with pipe(first()) to take only once call and it works, it displays only once. But after several click on the button, I don't know why but I always can't 'subscribe' anymore to the place because the variable goes directly to false.

Comment: @Lucas-ChrisNGUYEN there are many codes here, which variable ?

Comment: Sorry. This is the variable « subscribed » returned by the function isSubscribed(). This variable control the state of the button which allows to subscribe or unsubscribe to the place. It works for 2 clicks on the button but after, when I want to subscribe, the variable return true then instantanely false.